# $\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\alpha -\log(\log n))$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Can someone show why this limit is $0$?
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{n^\alpha}{(\log n)^{\log n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}  \frac{e^{\alpha \log n}}{e^{\log n \cdot\log(\log n)}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}  e^{\alpha \log n-\log n\cdot \log(\log n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}  e^{\log n(\alpha -\log(\log n))}=\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\alpha -\log(\log n))$$
with $\alpha>0$

I tried with L'Hôpital's rule but at a certain moment the limit becomes $+ \infty$, so I think it is that and not $0$

Comment: what is $ \alpha$?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a fixed number, then the limit is clearly not zero; it's $-\infty$.

Comment: ok, now i'm editing  the text

Comment: Your last step is completely incorrect: You can't just write $e^{\log n \cdot (\text{stuff})} = n \cdot (\text{stuff})$...

Comment: You are correct, form here $$\lim_{n\to \infty}  e^{\log n(\alpha -\log(\log n))}$$ note that  $${\log n(\alpha -\log(\log n))}\to -\infty$$

Comment: @Anne  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{n^\alpha}{(\log n)^{\log n}}=e^{\log{\frac{n^\alpha}{(\log n)^{\log n}}}} \to e^{-\infty}=0$$

indeed

$$\log{\frac{n^\alpha}{(\log n)^{\log n}}}=\alpha\log n-\log n\cdot\log\log n=\log n(\alpha-\log\log n)\to-\infty$$

Comment: I rather dislike it when people write things like $e^{-\infty} = 0$; I think it's misleading for students and isn't good practice.

Comment: @user296602 I understand, it's of course a symbolic way, and students should be aware about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your last step is wrong. You wrote

$$e^{\log n \cdot (\text{stuff})} = n \cdot (\text{stuff})$$

which is not a valid usage of the properties of exponents and logs. 
The correct conclusion is

$$e^{\log n \cdot (\text{stuff})} = n^{(\text{stuff})}$$

Keeping this in mind, you have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{\log n (\alpha - \log \log n)}$$

Now the exponent clearly tends to $-\infty$, and since $n \to \infty$ the overall limit is zero.

---

Alternatively, you could have noted at the start that

$$(\log n)^{\log n} = e^{\log n \log \log n} = n^{\log \log n}.$$

The exponent here grows without bound, so the denominator is vastly larger than the numerator - thus, the limit is zero.

Comment: I'd rather dislike when a limit is solved by explanation like "The exponent here grows without bound, so the denominator is vastly larger than the numerator - thus, the limit is zero", it is an uncorrect way misleading for students. You should use math argument and not qualitative and meaningless argument to determine the limit.

Comment: or phrases as "Now the exponent clearly tends to $-\infty$" are we doing mathematics or philosophy here? really a bad answer!

Comment: @gimusi "Tends to" is different from "=". Writing $e^{-\infty} = 0$ is nonsensical and wrong. Writing $e^{-x} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ is correct. Qualitative $\ne$ meaningless. I'm sorry that you're frustrated about the downvote on your answer, but taking it out on mine won't fix that.

Comment: I'm not frustrated at all, the fact is that I don't like such kind of suggestion form arrogant and pedantic people!

Comment: @user296602 i don't agree with you with the final limit

Comment: @gimusi Pointing out errors is neither arrogant nor pedantic, per se. Manipulating infinity as if it were a real number is dangerous and misleading at best, while describing a quantity as "growing without bound" is correct and standard terminology. That being said, it seems strange that you're criticizing my answer as being too imprecise....

Comment: @user296602 Indeed Anne is get confused as you can see, it is not a good way to explain limit!

Comment: @user296602 i'm referring to what user wrote...stuff=$\alpha - log(logn)$

Comment: @user296602 but what are you talking about, it is a allowed way and convention widely adopted to express the result in a short way, didn't ever see $\sum \frac1n = +\infty$? Are really a philosopher?!?!

Comment: @Anne indeed it is a very confusing argument, let use mathematical approach, your way was good, as already pointed out you only need to fix the last step and the limit is done!

Comment: @user296602 FYI take a look here for some example using such kind of symbolic use of $\infty$, be aware about it! https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcOneDIRECTORY/liminfsol1directory/LimInfSol1.html

Comment: @gimusi If someone doesn't understand the difference between writing that the sum of the harmonic series is infinite and doing arithmetic with infinities, then that's a good opportunity to learn more real analysis. And that would probably be a more pleasant and productive time than trying to insult people by calling them philosophers (if that even is an insult... I'm honestly confused).

Comment: @anne Without seeing your work in the final limit, I don't know where your calculation went wrong. The limit is indeed zero,  precisely because $a - \log \log n$ tends towards $-\infty.$

Comment: @user296602 I see you are a bit confused indeed, as you can see after your comment I wrote that I understand you observation but I have also added that I've used $e^{-\infty}=0$ with a precise symbolic meaning which is indeed the same used for the series, if you can't catch that simple concept I would say that not, you are not neither a philosopher!

Comment: @gimusi, it seems that gaining 32k reputation in just 3 months twisted your mind a bit. The above answer is absolutely fine. Please stop quarrelling with other users, or else your attitude will be flagged to a moderator.

Comment: @AlexM You are asking me to stop querreling with this kind of rude behavior? Maybe your mind is also twisted a bit for others reasons! This answer in my opinion is a bad answer for the reasons I gave here above. Indeed the asker get confused after reading that. Morover note that userxyz started the querrel affirming that my ansew was wrong. I really appreciate suggestions and observations but not when given by this kind of person. It is of course a my own opinion and you should respect this as I will respect your one. Regards

Comment: @gimusi I pointed out one specific issue that I had with your answer that you could have fixed with a five character edit, and I would have removed the downvote. You chose to escalate this by leaving several typo-riddled insults calling me rude and arrogant (though I still don't know why you think "philosopher" is a bad word...). If there is indeed a quarrel, then you're the one sustaining it. I would suggest that you simply move on to better things.

Answer (score 0):

ok now I see that the limit becomes

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{\alpha -\log(\log n)}$$
with $\alpha>0$

but the form is indeterminated and the hopital rule complicates the things

Comment: You don't need l'Hopital, and l'Hopital, with few exception, is not a good tool to solve limit!

Comment: morover note that l'hopital can't be used for sequences, you could refer to the correspondent function but in general their limits are nor equivalent and you should prove that this equivalence holds. For the sequecences you suould refer to Stolz-Cesaro https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem but as just noted you really don't need this kind of tools for this limit.

Comment: This is not an indeterminate form, @Anne.